# Why does $\mathbb{E}(X)=\lim_{s \uparrow 1 } G'(s)$ holds?

Tags: probability-theory, power-series

Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{N}_0$ be a random variable and $G_X(s):=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0} \mathbb{P}(X=k)\; *s^k$ the generating function which is defined for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ where the series is convergent. It now holds that $\mathbb{E}(X)=\lim_{s \uparrow 1 } G'(s)$.

Three Questions:

1. What does $\lim_{s \uparrow 1}$ mean in the context of complex numbers (there is no ordering)?
2. Proof: For $|s|<1, G(s)$ is defined and differentiable such that $ \lim_{s \uparrow 1}G'(s)=\lim_{s \uparrow 1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k s^{k-1} \mathbb{P}(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}(X=k)=\mathbb{E}(X) $

Does the second equality holds since we can put the $\lim$ inside because $G'(s)$ is continuous?

3. Is the statement also true while using $\lim_{s \to 1}$ instead of $\lim_{s \uparrow 1}$?

Comment: I think it means the limit is taken as $s$ increases to $1$ *as a real number*. “Putting the limit inside” can be justified by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: The limit is through real numbers increasing to $1$. Interchange of sum and limit is justified by Montone Convergence Theorem. If $EX <\infty$ then you can take left hand limit also.

Comment: ok thanks for your responses

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  how to exactly use the monotone convergence theorem to justify the interchange?